# std::this_thread::sleep_for() sleep infinite

Tags: c++, multithreading, sleep

So I have the main thread communicating with other threads, and at some point I want the sub threads to sleep one at a time, but when I use the `sleep_for` method and put in 2 seconds it never stop sleeps, but with valgrind it does stop sleep, without, it dont work.
Here's my code:

```
            int cookTime = (int)_currPizza->getCookTime() * this->_multiplier;
            printf("cook time %d\n", cookTime);
            // cookTime is 2;
            printf("start cooking\n");
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(cookTime));
            printf("end cooking\n");
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and please clarifiy how you know that it sleeps infinite

Comment: It doesnt print the "end cooking\n" that's how i know

Comment: Try flushing the buffered IO after the "end cooking" printf.. You can do this with `fflush(stdout)`. If you post a simplified complete example (i.e. something we can run, we can't run this as it is) then people may be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait for finishing the job of created thread you should call thread.join() in  creator thread.